# Student Visa - Refugee

Tags: canada, student-visa, indian-citizens, refugees

Im Indian and I had a "refugee status" in Brazil for 1 month.Now im in India.There is no marks in my passport other than Indian & Brazil immigration stamp.Will it be a problem if i apply for a Student Visa in Canada..??

1.If yes, is there any solution..??

2.If i apply for new passport and cancelling the present one,can it be helpful..??

3.Is there any way to trace my travel history from cancelled passport number..??

*There is no criminal case against me in both countries till now.( India & Brazil)

Please help...!!

Comment: 2. No. 3. Yes. Have you abandoned your refugee status? Returning to your country of original citizenship often cancels refugee status.

Comment: Yes Mam.
I have returned to my own country.I stayed in Brazil for 40 days. While applying for Canadian Student Visa there is a explanation letter where i have to mention this travel history.But i don't know what to write.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

In applying for a student visa to Canada, you will need to detail your travel and immigration history, including your time in Brazil, and that you applied for and were granted refugee status. You may need to attach additional documents explaining the situation, and why you abandoned that claim. Omission of any relevant information can be cause for visa refusal or worse; refugee status by Brazil (or any country) is pertinent. A new passport will not avoid, or resolve, the issue.